# What's wrong with Turkish tap water?

Tags: health, turkey, tap-water

I've tried finding an answer for this but without success. Most people just say "don't drink it" without telling one why. The only reason being "it's bad".

As one having studied biology and chemistry I find the answers unacceptable and I wonder if anyone know why it's bad?

---

The water at my hotel looks fine, smells fine, tastes fine and doesn't make me sick.

Comment: Huuuh? I've been drinking it for 9 months, I cannot say there is anything bad about it, it does have high level of minerals, and it shows. It does not smell or taste any different than bottled water